# ImageView stop being clicable when check box is on part of it

Tags: android, checkbox, layout, imageview, gallery

I create simple GridView Gallery. I display some photos. Now I'm trying to put on them check box. Check box is visible on my Images but now click action doesn't work (Before onItemClick I zoomed picture). So the idea is that if I click on photo except place for check box it zoom, but if I click on checkbox it checked/unchecked.

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@integer/width"
        android:layout_height="@integer/height"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code so that I can check it

Comment: ohh man hole gallery it's quite complicated ? it's useless to put it because, If I remove just this checkbox in layout all this works good I mean photo is zooming etc but checkbox act like it will be on top this ImageView but he is wrap_content so I don't get it

Comment: Instead of relative layout add frame layout and try again , let me know and remove "android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these attributtes to your xml CheckBox

```
 android:clickable="false"
 android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: when I add android:clickable="false" I can't use checkbox :) but this second line do job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
       <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

       </FrameLayout>
```